# If $X_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$, and $Y_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}Z\sim Normal$, does $X_nY_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$?

Tags: convergence, asymptotics, slutsky-theorem

If $X_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$, and $Y_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}Z\sim Normal$, does $X_nY_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$?   According to Slutsky theorem, I can directly get $X_nY_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}0$, I'm wondering if this also implies  $X_nY_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$. Thanks!

Comment: [Convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution_to_a_constant_implies_convergence_in_probability)

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks! I just saw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### In short

You can express a lower limit for the probability that $Y_n X_n$ is within some boundary $\epsilon =  \epsilon_y \cdot \epsilon_x$ by the product of the probability that $Y_n$ is within some boundary boundary $\epsilon_y$ (which can be made as close to 1 as you like by increasing $n$ and $\epsilon_y$) and the probability that $X_n$ is within some boundary $\epsilon_x$.

So $$Pr(\vert X_nY_n \vert \leq \epsilon) \geq Pr(\vert X_n\vert \leq \epsilon_x = \epsilon/\epsilon_y) \cdot Pr(\vert Y_n \vert \leq \epsilon_y)$$

You can make  $Pr(\vert Y_n \vert \leq \epsilon_y)\to 1$ by increasing $\epsilon_y$ and $n$ and while this increase of $\epsilon_y$ makes $\epsilon_x$ smaller, there is some $n$ such that you can make $Pr(\vert X_n \vert \leq \epsilon_x)\to 1$ by making $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @T34driver I hope this simple proof is sufficient for you. I had been trying to write down a larger more rigorous proof with quantifiers, but it gets very cluttered. I could also add a graph to help the intuition (the image in my head is that the CDF of $Y_n$ gets closer to the CDF of $Z$, the normal, and with $X_n$ we squeeze/scale it, with a certain probability, below some boundary).

Comment: Yes, it's sufficiently clear!